# simplify OleDbDataReader code

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbdatareader

I made a program, that reads data in the database I use the `OleDbDataReader` but the problem is I have different tables, this codes works perfectly but I found it a little bit "hardcoded" or `recursive` here is my sample code

```
        private void loadMilk()
        {
            cn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select* from Milk", cn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Milk.Add(reader["Product"].ToString());
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
```

I need to repeat this again and again just to read what's on the other table (e.g., `"select* from Fruit` then `"select* from Classics`....) Is there any way so that I will not repeat this code again and again?
thanks.:)

Comment: You could make your life simpler still by storing Milk and Fruit in the same table with an ID identifying the type of product. In fact this would generally be recommended.

Comment: I am commenting here because it's not directly related to the question, but I'd avoid selecting all the columns unless you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refactor that method into something like this:

```
private IList<string> Load(string tableName, string columnName)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    cn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = null;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("select* from {0}", tableName), cn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        result.Add(reader[columnName].ToString());
    }
    cn.Close();

    return result;
}
```

Your code sample will be:

```
var milkItems = Load("Milk", "Product");
var classicItems = Load("Classics", "..."); //Enter the column here.
```

**Edit**:

You might want something a little more specific (eg. storing a `List<SomeObject>` instead of just `List<string>`). Let's suppose you sometimes you want to return a list of `Person`, and also you want to read a list of `Building`. Then you can write something like this (**not compiled & tested**):

```
private IList<T> Load<T>(string tableName, Func<OleDbDataReader, T> selector)
{
    IList<T> result = new List<T>();
    cn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = null;
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("select* from {0}", tableName), cn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        result.Add(selector(reader));
    }
    cn.Close();

    return result;
}
```

and you can call it like:

```
Func<OleDbDataReader, Person> selector = x => new Person { Name = x["Person"].ToString() };
Load("People", selector);
```

Comment: yes, the `result` code is a list, so if I change the `table` I also need to change the `ListName`

Comment: @AlfredSanz If you're always getting a list of `string`, you can use the 1st code I wrote. If you're getting `objects` (eg. `Person`, etc.) you can use the other way.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void loadMilk(string TableName, string itemValue)
        {
            string SQLString = String.Format("select * from {0}",TableName);

            cn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SQLString, cn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Milk.Add(reader[ItemValue].ToString());
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what type "Milk" is.
Try:

```
private void loadObjectsFrom(string tableName, object obj, string column)
        {
            cn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select* from " + tableName, cn);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                obj.Add(reader[column].ToString());
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: because `obj` is a list :)

Comment: @AlfredSanz in your code, but not in this one. `obj` is an `object` in this code.

Comment: yes, @OscarMederos my parameters should include the list in there. I was just giving him an idea of what he should use. obj should be a list not object.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a table name as a parameter:

```
    private void loadMilk(string tableName)
    {
        cn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("select* from {0}",tableName), cn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Milk.Add(reader["Product"].ToString());
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
```